# Derived McKay correspondence between a weighted projective plane and a Hirzebruch surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, algebraic-surfaces, algebraic-stacks

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of $\text{ch}(k) =0$.

Let $\mathbb{P}(1,1,2)$ be the weighted projective plane of weight $(1,1,2)$ as a stack.
Let $\mathbf{P}(1,1,2)$ be the weighted projective plane of weight $(1,1,2)$ as a scheme.
Let $\mathbb{F}_2$ be the Hirzebruch surface of degree 2.

$\mathbf{P}(1,1,2)$ has a unique singularity and $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the minimal resolution.

From derived McKay correspondence, we have an equivalence of derived categories
$$
\Phi:D^b(\text{Coh}(\mathbb{P}(1,1,2))) \overset{\simeq}{\rightarrow} D^b(\text{Coh}(\mathbb{F}_2)).
$$

**Question**

How is this functor $\Phi$ defined?

For example, what are the images of canonical line bundles $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(1,1,2)}(i)$ by $\Phi$ ?
Of course, I am also interested in the image of any other sheaf.

Any comment is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

One choice of $\Phi$ acts as
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(1,1,2)}(2i) \mapsto 
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}_2}(i(e + 2f)),
$$
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(1,1,2)}(2i+1) \mapsto 
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}_2}(i(e + 2f)+f),
$$
where $e$ is the exceptional section and $f$ is the fiber of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. What are the preimages of $\mathcal{O}(e)$ and $\mathcal{O}_e$

Comment: Note that any four consecutive objects in the list form a full exceptional collection. You can use it to decompose the objects of your interest and then translate to the other side using the action on the exceptional collection.